# Jar added to build path does not appear in the archive file (broker archive)

Tags: eclipse, jar, build, toolkit, messagebroker

I have ojdbc5.jar referenced in the build path of a java project in one of my message broker toolkit workspaces. the toolkit is built on top of eclipse. So when I build a broker archive (its a bar similar to a ear or war), I dont see the ojdbc5 jar in it. I see it in the archive file if I build it in a different workspace with a similar java project. I suspected that the workspace is corrupted and tried creating a new workspace with the same non-working code. Still wouldnt work. I have tried all the options listed on the same issue on stackoverflow. none of them helped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

did you try menu Project > Build for mqsipackagebar ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the jar would be physically present or not depending on how the jar is added. If I created a variable for the physical path, where the jar is present, extended that variable and added it to the libraries under Properties->Java Build Path, the jar wouldnt be physically present in the bar. But if I added the jar directly from the physical file location, it would be present in the bar. Some learning with a lot of head-scratching!